# using List with values come from SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

```
List<Foo> bar= new List<Foo>()
{
  new Foo(){ name= "xxx", sname= "yyy", age= 22 },
  new Foo(){ name= "zzz", sname= "ccc", age= 18 },
  new Foo(){ name= "aaa", sname= "bbb", age= 14 },
  new Foo(){ name= "ddd", sname= "fff", age= 26 },
  new Foo(){ name= "uuu", sname= "hhh", age= 17 },
};
```

I want to get the name, surname, age from a database table.
How can I match the values with this list?

I want to get the data; `Select name From FooBar Where Id = 4` assume that the return value is John and then I want to assign the John to name property of

```
List<Foo> bar= new List<Foo>
```

and the question is how can I do this with ADO.NET?

Comment: You'll need to provide a lot more details. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: What data access method?  ADO.NET? Linq to SQL? Entity Framework? nHibernate? ...?

Comment: The data access method is which I want to use : ADO.NET

Comment: according to comments, I edit my question, still is it complex in order to understand?

Comment: I am waiting another downvote :)

Comment: @Csharp Er: What do you mean by match the values with this list? Is the list populated from the database already? Are you just looking to query the list for a certain name or ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure of what you're asking, but I'll go on the assumption that you might be looking to query a list of data that was returned from the database.

You can use this code to query the list:

```
List<Bar> bar = new List<Bar>() 
    { 
        new Bar() { Id = 1, Name = "John Smith" }, 
        new Bar() { Id = 2, Name = "Jane Doe" }, 
        new Bar() { Id = 3, Name = "Joe Johnson" } 
    };

//query the bar list and select the name 
string name = bar.Where(x => x.Id == 2).Select(x => x.Name).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I want to assign the value which return from the query to bar.Name

Comment: that is to say I want to compose bar dynamically via sql query